# Connect virtual machine to host via IEEE1394, USB or Serial Port?

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, vmware-workstation

I have a host machine (Laptop, Win 7 Home Premium x64) running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on VMWare Workstation 9. I've got this system set up for UMDF driver development, because I need a target machine to debug drivers on. However, because I'm developing drivers for Win 7 (x86 and x64), I cannot connect to the virtual machine on via a simple network connection. Connection methods are outlined [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have tried a few different pieces of software (mostly `Eltima` software), and have Google'd every combination of phrases that I can think of. I can't find any information on this anywhere. I don't just need to share data between the machines, I need a more "physical" connection.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if there's another (preferably more simple) way of doing it?

Comment: I must be missing something here. The link provided says network connections are supported?

Comment: Pays to read: "If your target computer is running a version of Windows prior to Windows 8, you cannot use a network connection for debugging; you must use a USB, 1394, or serial connection."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up debugging of a virtual machine using named pipes as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **Setting Up the Target Virtual Machine**
>
> In the virtual machine, in an elevated Command Prompt window, enter the following commands.
>
> `bcdedit /debug on`
>
> `bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport: n baudrate: 115200`
>
> *where n is the number of a COM port on the virtual machine.*
>
> Reboot the virtual machine.
>
> In the virtual machine, configure the COM port to map to a named pipe. The debugger will connect through this pipe. For more information about how to create this pipe, see your virtual machine's documentation.
>
> **Starting the Debugging Session Using WinDbg**
>
> On the host computer, open WinDbg.
>
> On the File menu, choose Kernel Debug.
>
> In the Kernel Debugging dialog box, open the COM tab.
>
> Check the Pipe box, and check the Reconnect box. For Baud Rate, enter 115200. For Resets, enter 0.
>
> If the debugger is running on the same computer as the virtual machine, enter the following for Port.
>   \.\pipe\PipeName.
>
> If the debugger is running on a different computer from the virtual machine, enter the following for Port.
>   \VMHost\pipe\PipeName
>
> Click OK.

To configure the named pipe in VMWare Workstation, open the virtual machine settings while the VM is powered off. Add a device:

[image]

Select a new serial port:

[image]

Choose named pipe:

[image]

And select the appropriate settings:

[image]

Some of the information is outdated, but you might be able to find a little help from [these](http://www.etdot.com/2008/04/16/windbg-and-vmware/) [blog](http://silverstr.ufies.org/lotr0/windbg-vmware.html) [posts](http://www.arkf.net/blog/?p=199).

Comment: Excellent! I haven't tried it yet, but it all makes sense, and +1 for excellent layout. Thanks!